# Auto_increment with Perl SQLite

Tags: sql, perl, sqlite, auto-increment

I am having trouble with auto increment in SQLite using Perl.

Database design:

```
$dbh->do( "CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Users` (
  `UserID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE ,
  `First_Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `Last_Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `Email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `Password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL )" ) ;

$dbh->do( "CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Files` (
  `FileID` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `UserID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `File_Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `File` BLOB NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`FileID`, `UserID`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Files_Users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`UserID` )
    REFERENCES `Users` (`UserID` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)" ) ;
```

The query:

```
$dbh->do( "INSERT INTO Files ( UserID, File_Name )
                VALUES ( '$_[0]', '$_[1]' )" ) ;
```

Even though I have identified the FileID as being both an AUTO_INCREMENT and a PRIMARY KEY, when I add a new field using the above query the FileID is left blank and isn't incremented automatically.  Any thoughts?  Have I designed the tables wrong?

Cheers,

Nate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend you to create a primary key on Files table with the FileID field exclusively (you have two fields). And I think you have a typo: it's AUTOINCREMENT, (you type AUTO_INCREMENT). See this: http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: AUTO_INCREMENT is mysql's syntax. Confusing indeed.

Comment: Didn't you get an SQL syntax error for that SQL statement? Oh, that's right, you probably didn't check -- Unless you did set RaiseError.

Comment: Actually, I got AUTO_INCREMENT from http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.616/DBI.pm, as AUTOINCREMENT produced a syntax error.